# Converting heavy geopackage file to lighter format using QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have a 30GB geopackage file containing 1M least cost paths inside (single vectors). As I want to share this in a repository e.g. Zenodo, I need to transform it to a lighter and manageable format.

Any ideas what could I do?

I tried to transform it directly in QGIS to a shapefile, but it is still too heavy to be manageable.

Comment: You cant create shapefiles larger than 2 GB. What is the problem with the geopackage? Are you saying you have 1M layers inside one geopackage?

Comment: Shapefile is more *flimsy* than lightweight, and its failure to support modern datatypes (datetime, NULL integer, and strings longer than 254) make it questionable as a target for data simplification.

Comment: If 1M = 30gb it seems like your data coulld to be cleaed up. Or divided own into smaller files.

Comment: Did you try any compression methods like 7z or zip?  Are your least cost paths amenable to simplification/generalization?